# mongo-connector does not launch

Tags: mongodb, neo4j

I would like to use mongo-connector to stream a collection from a MongoDB database to Neo4j.

I followed the official Neo4j documentation at this link: https://neo4j.com/developer/mongodb/. The MongoDB replica set is successfully initiated. After running the command ...

> `mongo-connector -m localhost:27017 -t http://localhost:7474/db/data -d neo4j_doc_manager`

... I do not get any error, but there is no message output confirming the successful connection between MongoDB and Neo4j.

The mongo-connector log file is empty and  typing ...

> `mongo-connector --help`

... in the prompt does not output the usual function and optional flag description. Any idea of what is going on?

I am using Windows 10 and Neo4j CE 3.2.1 with the default installation (from .exe).

Comment: Added formatting.

Comment: is a `oplog.timestamp` file created?

Comment: What does mongo-connector --help yield? If nothing, then check if the path for the mongo-connector executable is included in the environment.

Comment: The oplog.timestamp file is not created and mongo-connector --help yields no output.